# how I could send email with groovy error (com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at)

Tags: java, email, groovy

this code fail with authentification

this is my code

I dont know because dont work

I dont know because dont work

I dont know because dont work
please help me

```
@Grab(group = 'com.sun.mail', module = 'javax.mail', version = '1.6.0')

import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*




MAILER_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"  // "smtp-relay.gmail.com"


RECIPIENT_EMAIL = "mygmail@gmail.com"
date_time = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
props = new Properties()
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


    props.put("mail.host", MAILER_HOST);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props)
    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)
    message.setFrom("no.reply@example.org")
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(RECIPIENT_EMAIL))
    message.setSubject("A Test email ${date_time}")
    message.setText("This is a sample email message!")

    Transport.send(message)
```

Comment: The error message you didn't bother to include *literally has a link in it*.

Comment: what link  your refer?

Comment: "Learn more at..."